# Insert custom React component into a String variable with html content

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a string which contains HTML tags like this:

```
<div class="header">Hello!</div>
<div class="body">How are you?</div>
<div class="footer">Good bye!</div>
```

I need to replace `<div class="body">How are you?</div>` with my custom react component.
My react component display the content with data that is dynamically fetched from an API.
for example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function App(){
    const [books, setBooks] = . useState(null);

    const apiURL = "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books?pageSize=30";

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(apiURL)

        setBooks(response.data) 
    }

    return (
        <div>
           {books.map((book, index) => {
                return <p key={index}>{book.title}</P>
           })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

How can I replace html string with react component and render both the html tags and the new components in the string?

Answer (score 0):

use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. [check docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
  return (
        <div>
           {books.map((book, index) => {
                return  <div key={index} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: book.title}}></div>
           })}
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: My issue is to insert the react component into `<div class="body">..</div>`. React component itself works well.

Comment: where is `<div class="body">How are you?</div>`, written

Comment: I have read the HTML file as a string using readfilesync function.
`<div class="body">How are you?</div>` is the one part of that string.
I need to insert the react component into that `div`.
PS: I want to do this in Next.js